# Average of last 3 months (SQL vertica)

Tags: sql, average, vertica

I need to find the average days past due for the last 3 months for each client. Not as a rolling/moving average, but one time number, always calculating the last 3 months, no matter if the data changes.

For example now the last data I have is from Sept 2022, so I need the average of Sept 2022, August 2022 and July 2022. But if the data changes and now I have October 2022, then I would need average of Oct, Sept, August and so on.

I tried this but it calculates wrong

```
CREATE TABLE AVERAGE_dpd
AS (
SELECT "SUM_WEIGHTED_AVG_PERMONTH"."NAME",
AVG("SUM_WEIGHTED_AVG_PERMONTH"."SUM") 
OVER (PARTITION BY "SUM_WEIGHTED_AVG_PERMONTH"."NAME"
order by MONTH ("SUM_WEIGHTED_AVG_PERMONTH"."LAST DAY OF MONTH_NETDUEDATE") desc 
rows between 2 preceding and CURRENT ROW) 
as AVG3Months
FROM "SUM_WEIGHTED_AVG_PERMONTH");
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please post some sample data and your expected output Also what you are getting from this query.

Comment: I would like to receive this 

Name         AVG DPD 3 Months
Client 01     16,76
Client 02      5.75
Client 03      -13.95

as data I have the value of DPD (days past due) for all of the months for the year for each client, but I only need to find the avg for the last 3 available months

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are expecting this result:

```
 client_name | avg_last_3mth
-------------+--------------
 Client 01   |         16.76
 Client 02   |          5.75
 Client 03   |        -13.95
```

So I assume you have something like this as input data (and this is how we usually like the data to accompany the question):

```
month_begin | client_name | dpd
------------+-------------+----
2022-01-05  | Client 01   |  12
2022-01-06  | Client 01   |  14
2022-01-07  | Client 01   |  18
2022-01-08  | Client 01   |  17
2022-01-05  | Client 02   |  12
2022-01-06  | Client 02   |  14
2022-01-07  | Client 02   |  18
2022-01-08  | Client 02   |  17
2022-01-05  | Client 03   |  12
2022-01-06  | Client 03   |  14
2022-01-07  | Client 03   |  18
2022-01-08  | Client 03   |  17
```

With this input data, you probably want the rows with `month_begin` of the first of the current month (`TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH')`), plus the two previous months. And this is what I do, then I obviously group by the client name:

```
WITH
-- input data I made up, don't use in query ..
dpd(month_begin,client_name,dpd) AS (
            SELECT DATE '2022-05-01','Client 01',12
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-06-01','Client 01',14
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01','Client 01',18
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-08-01','Client 01',17        
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-05-01','Client 02', 2
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-06-01','Client 02', 4
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01','Client 02', 8        
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-08-01','Client 02', 7
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-05-01','Client 03',22        
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-06-01','Client 03',24        
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01','Client 03',28        
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-08-01','Client 03',27
)
-- real query starts here ..
SELECT
  client_name
, AVG(dpd)::NUMERIC(5,2)  AS avg_last_3mth
FROM dpd
WHERE month_begin >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH') - '2 MONTHS'::INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH
GROUP BY 
  client_name;
-- out  client_name | avg_last_3mth 
-- out -------------+---------------
-- out  Client 02   |          6.33
-- out  Client 01   |         16.33
-- out  Client 03   |         26.33
```